# What does "bottleneck" mean in terms of bandwidth?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

What is a "bottleneck", particularly when used in terms of network bandwidth?

Comment: Depends on the context, more number of clients are streaming/accessing from a server which is not able to handle them due to the limited bandwidth it has.

Comment: These are good answers in terms of communications bandwidth. Sadly the term also gets applied to software, leading people to look for "slow code". A better model is a function is like a credit card. "Pro" is convenience - it makes you more productive. "Con" is convenience - it makes you more wasteful. Multiply this over several layers of abstraction! If you spend too much money with a credit card, do you say it is a "bottleneck"? I think a better word is "drain".

Answer (score 19):

A bottleneck is the "slowest" part of a system. If you examine a beer bottle, the neck is smaller than the base and so limits the amount of sweet wonderful nectar that you can drink. Mmmm! Beeer! (sorry, got carried away).

In terms of bandwidth, it's the slowest device in the chain. For example, it makes little difference having gigabit ethernet on your PC if your router only runs at 10meg. The router there is the bottleneck.

And it doesn't matter how fast your ethernet card and router and internet infrastructure are, if the site you're trying to download from is running with a 1200/75 acoustic modem from the early '80s. The other end is the bottleneck in that case.

Bottlenecks are everywhere. Your network devices, the disk in your PC, having to fetch from RAM rather than L2 cache, critical paths on your Gantt chart, trying to walk your kids to school when one is a 7yo speed daemon and the other a 5yo "want to stop and look at every single god-damned flower"-type :-)

Basically, it's the thing that, if it was faster, would make the system (as a whole) faster. It's the bottlenecks where you need to optimise since the return on investment should be higher there.

Answer (score 0):

Bottleneck terminology is used in many areas within the computer science realm (and in many outside), in a telecommunication context first one should understand what is **throughput** to understand **Bottleneck**  as the two are closely related so:

> **Throughput** briefly is the rate of successful packets
> delivery over a communication channel.

Now let's consider an example, a client and a server con-nected by two communication links and a router.

[image]

Consider the throughput for a file transfer from the server to the client. Let **R_{s}** denote the rate of the link between the server and the router; and **R_{c}** denote the rate of the link between the router and the client.

Suppose that the only bits being sent in the entire network are those from the server to the client. We now ask, in this ideal scenario, **what is the server-to-client throughput?**

To answer this question, we may think of bits as fluid and com-munication links as pipes. Clearly, the server cannot pump bits through its link at a rate faster than **R_{s}** bps; and the router cannot forward bits at a rate faster than **R_{c}** bps.
If **R_{s} < R_{c}** , then the bits pumped by the server will “flow” right through the router and arrive at the client at a rate of **R_{s}** bps, giving a throughput of **R_{s}** bps. If, on the other hand, **R_{c} < R_{s}** , then the router will not be able to forward bits as quickly as it receives them. In this case, bits will only leave the router at rate **R_{c}** , giving an end-to-end throughput of **R_{c}** . (Note also that if bits continue to arrive at the router at rate **R_{s}** , and continue to leave the router at **R_{c}** , the backlog of bits at the router waiting for transmission to the client will grow and grow—a most undesirable situation! Thus, for this simple two-link network, the throughput is **min{R_{c},R_{s}}**, that is, it is the transmission rate of the bottleneck link.

So now can give a formal sweat and comprehensive definition of bottleneck:

> Bottleneck in a communications context, is a point in the network
> where the transmission rate is impaired or stopped entirely.
> Effectively, a bottleneck results when there is not enough data
> handling capacity to accommodate the current volume of traffic, As a
> result, data flow (or transmission rate)slows down to the speed of the
> slowest point in the data path. That is min{link_{1}, link_{2}....}

Curtsy (Computer Networking A Top-Down Approach,EIGHTH EDITION,James F. Kurose • Keith W. Ross).