# Meaning of bottle neck?

Tags: performance

What is a bottle neck problem (in any programming language with computer)?

Comment: It's "bottle".  Please use a dictionary.

Comment: When I turn my 2-liter bottle upside down and have to wait for the liquid to come out as it's limited by the narrow neck of the bottle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "bottleneck" mean in terms of bandwidth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062325/what-does-bottleneck-mean-in-terms-of-bandwidth)

Comment: Think of a horse race. A bottleneck would be if there were a place in the track where the horses could only get through single-file at a walk. A better model is if there are other race tracks attached to the first one, and the horses take mindless detours.

Answer (score 2):

What is a bottleneck problem in a bottle? That's a good place to start. The neck of a bottle is much skinnier than the main part of the bottle and the rate at which you can pour out liquid is limited by the amount of fluid that can pass through the neck. So... the analogy is made in many place. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#Von_Neumann_bottleneck

or from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck_(engineering)#Engineering :

"In computer programming, tracking down bottlenecks (sometimes known as "hot spots" - sections of the code that execute most frequently - i.e. have the highest execution count) is called performance analysis. Reduction is usually achieved with the help of specialized tools, known as performance analyzers or profilers. The objective being to make those particular sections of code perform as fast as possible to improve overall algorithmic efficiency."

It's a good thing to think about, and one of the reason wise programmers tell you not to bother optimizing every routine you write, because there are some which are executed a lot more than others and are the ones that really matter to the overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck#Bottlenecks_in_software

Comment: That particular link, and the further links within it, are among my favorite examples of the group-think mediocrity you find on Wikipedia.